# reflection - getMethods()/getDeclaredMethods() (Duplicate Methods!)

Tags: java, reflection, jvm

Consider the following simple Java code snippet:

```
package p;   

class Sup {
    public Sup f() {return null;}
}

class Sub extends Sup {
    @Override public Sub f() {return null;}
}
```

I used Java Reflection to list all the (declared) methods of the class `Sub` as follows.

```
for(Method m : Sub.class.getDeclaredMethods())
            System.out.println(m);
```

But I received an output like the following:

> public p.Sub p.Sub.f()
>
> public p.Sup p.Sub.f()

The first line is pretty reasonable, but the second one confuses me (even though its return type is different). Please explain why do I get the method `public p.Sup p.Sub.f()`?  How does JVM distinguishes between the two methods at runtime during virtual method call resolution?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Sotirios Delimanolis... That was a nasty problem...